# Join using 2 'alternative' columns from one table

Tags: sql, join, teradata

I have 2 large tables like bellow in Teradata. I need to join them so that:

- all records from Table A are kept - like A left join B
- join is on A.client_id=B.client_id_1
- but if B.client_id_1 is null, it can join on A.client_id=B.client_id_2

Table A

| client_id | details_a |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abc |
| 2 | def |
| 3 | ghi |
| 4 | jkl |

Table B

| client_id_1 | client_id_2 | details_b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 123 |
| null | 2 | 456 |
| 3 | 3 | 789 |

The result should be like:

| client_id | details_a | client_id_1 | client_id_2 | details_b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 1 | null | 123 |
| 2 | def | null | 2 | 456 |
| 3 | ghi | 3 | 3 | 789 |
| 4 | jkl | null | null | null |

The tables are large and the join is part of a larger script (other joins using Table B)

I tried something like

```
Table A LEFT JOIN Table B
    ON (A.client_id = B.client_id_1 OR A.client_id = B.client_id_2)
```

But the result was product join that never finished.

I also want to avoid two left joins (on B.client_id_1 and on B.client_id_2) as it would result in having all columns from Table B twice. And the Table B is further used in following joins. Plus client_id=3 would have two records.

Any idea? And what is wrong with the JOIN using OR above?

Thanks, R.

Comment: Nothing wrong, semantically.

Comment: Two joins on different columns with coalesce in `select` list to get the desired columns from `tableB`. Very straightforward and should be quite fast

Comment: An ORed join-condition is worst case for Teradata's optimizer, the only solution is a *product join* as you noticed. If you got an XOR Kazi's solution is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use case statement:

```
Table A LEFT JOIN Table B
    ON (A.client_id = case when B.client_id_1 is null then B.client_id_2 else B.client_id_1 end)
```

oR Coalesce:

```
Table A LEFT JOIN Table B
    ON (A.client_id = Coalesce(B.client_id_1 ,B.client_id_2 ))
```

If B.client_id_1 is not null then Coalesce(B.client_id_1 ,B.client_id_2 ) will return B.client_id_1 but if it's null then the condition will return B.client_id_2 .

Comment: Yes, thank you. This is exactly I was looking for. I am a bit ashamed by the coalesce solution - this could have come to my mind. I had no idea case could be used in this way. Great.

Comment: You are most welcome. It was a nice problem to work on. Best wishes.